# Optimization of calculating time to a future event

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one with experimental data for 57 subjects in 2 blocks of 250 trials each (28500 rows total) and one that has the subject, row, block and trial number of all trials where a drift correction was performed (160 rows total). Here is what the relevant columns look like in the two files:

Experimental data:

```
> head(dori.np[c("userid","blocknum","trialnum")])
   userid blocknum trialnum
26      1        1        1
27      1        1        2
28      1        1        3
29      1        1        4
30      1        1        5
31      1        1        6
```

Drift correction data:

```
> head(driftCor.user)
  userid driftTrials blocknum trialnum
1      4          61        1       61
2      4         140        1      140
3      5           1        1        1
4      6         208        1      208
5      8          71        1       71
6      8         197        1      197
```

What I want to do is calculate for every trial for each participant how far (in trials) the nearest drift correction is in the future. Right now I am doing it with nested loops, but it takes a very long time for it to run.

```
numTilDrifCor<-numeric(0)
for (i in driftCor.user$userid) {
  temp1 <- subset(driftCor.user,driftCor.user$userid==i)

  for (j in temp1$blocknum) {
    temp2<-subset(dori.np,dori.np$userid==i & dori.np$blocknum==j)
    driftTrials<-subset(temp1,temp1$blocknum==j)

    n <- 1
    for (k in 1:250) {
      if (n <= length(driftTrials$trialnum)) {
        diff <- driftTrials$trialnum[n] - k

        if (diff > 0) {
          numTilDrifCor <- c(numTilDrifCor,diff)
        } else if (diff == 0) {
          numTilDrifCor <- c(numTilDrifCor,0)
          n <- n + 1
        }

      } else {
        numTilDrifCor <- c(numTilDrifCor,NA)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to calculate. Given a user id `i` and a block number `j` of a particular row in `driftCor.user`, how do you calculate the desired result?

Comment: By way of example: for each userid there are 250 trials in each block numbered 1, 2, 3 ... 250. Also for each userid in each block there are some trials where a drift correction occurred. For example, let's say trials 61 and 140 were drift corrected trails for userid 1. I want to create a vector of values that is equal to the number of trials before the next drift correction like so: 60, 59, 58 ... 0, 78, 77, 76 .... 0, and then the rest NAs until the end of that block since there are no more future drift corrections. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like for each trial in `dori.np` (which has a userid, blocknum, and trialnum) you want to compute the number of trials before the next drift correction (or NA if there are no subsequent drift corrections); all drift corrections are stored in `driftCor.user`.

Let's consider a small example dataset:

```
(dori.np <- data.frame(userid=rep(1, 6), blocknum=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), trialnum=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)))
#   userid blocknum trialnum
# 1      1        1        1
# 2      1        1        2
# 3      1        1        3
# 4      1        2        1
# 5      1        2        2
# 6      1        2        3
(driftCor.user <- data.frame(userid=c(1, 1), blocknum=c(1, 1), driftTrials=c(1, 3)))
#   userid blocknum driftTrials
# 1      1        1           1
# 2      1        1           3
```

I would approach this problem using split-apply-combine:

1. Split `dori.np` by userid and blocknum
2. Look up the relevant drift corrections in `driftCor.user`
3. Calculate the distance to the next drift correction for each row of your `dori.np` subset in a single vectorized operation (I'll use `cut` to do this)
4. Combine all the results back together

Here's how that might look in base R (I assume here that `dori.np` is ordered first by userid and next by blocknum):

```
dori.np$nextDrift <- unlist(lapply(split(dori.np, paste(dori.np$userid, dori.np$blocknum)),
  function(x) {
    corrs <- sort(driftCor.user$driftTrials[driftCor.user$userid == x$userid[1] &
                                            driftCor.user$blocknum == x$blocknum[1]])
    if (length(corrs) == 0) {
      rep(NA, nrow(x))
    } else {
      corrs[cut(x$trialnum, c(0, corrs))] - x$trialnum
    }
  }
))
#   userid blocknum trialnum nextDrift
# 1      1        1        1         0
# 2      1        1        2         1
# 3      1        1        3         0
# 4      1        2        1        NA
# 5      1        2        2        NA
# 6      1        2        3        NA
```

I would imagine this would give you a significant efficiency boost because it uses vectorized operations to calculate the time until the next drift correction and it avoids growing a vector one element at a time (to see why this can slow down your code, check out the second circle of [the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)). While I've provided a base R solution here, many packages can also be used to perform these sorts of grouped operations, and some may yield further efficiency improvements (two that come to mind would be `data.table` and `dplyr`).